# Why does manually loading hyperref change the font size for captions in Tufte documents?

Tags: hyperref, captions, tufte

I'm using Tufte document classes and need to manually load `hyperref` rather than have it loaded by the Tufte class. So I'm using the `nohyper` option with the document class, and later use `\usepackage{hyperref}` in code.

When I do this, the font size for captions (though not footnotes) changes to that of body text:

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Body text.
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{agraphic}\caption{Caption text}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}` line, the caption font size is correct (whether I specify `nohyper` or not). As near as I can tell, except for some link coloring details and metadata assignment, I'm doing exactly the same thing that the Tufte class would do without the `nohyper` option.

Comment: Is the option `hyperfootnotes=false` the reason why you would load hyperref yourself?

Comment: Two great answers, each with a different emphasis. My needs are to preserve Tufte while getting as much of `hyperref` as I can get, so my choose is [Altermundus's](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46838/7844); but Werner's is more concise and appropriate for other uses.

Comment: then always use `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}{hyperref}` _before_ `\documentclass`, then you do not need all that tricks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know where the problem comes from but I'm not sure if my workaround is correct. Hyperref modifies `\caption`

**Update code with diabonas's comment**

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\makeatletter
\let\tufte@caption\@caption  
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\let\@caption\tufte@caption  
\begin{document}
Body text.
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{guilloche.png}\caption{Caption text}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you shouldn't restore `\caption` as it isn't changed by `tufte-handout` (only locally in a float environment) and you will lose the `hyperref`-specific change like this. (You can check yourself by using `\show\caption` both with and without the `noyper` option.) Otherwise, this workaround (i.e. restoring only `\@caption`) is fine.

Comment: [Werner's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46839/7844) (and the support for it) suggests that that "minimal intervention" is preferred; but this seems to do a better job of ensuring I get the Tufte captions intact. Is that true? What features of `hyperref` do I disable by taking this approach (vs. the one in Werner's answer)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I agree that a minimal intervention is preferable but it's difficult to know if hyperref makes others modifications. You need to look at the complete code of `\@caption`. In one case you need to load "etoolbox" it's a fine package but some users prefer to load a "minimal" number of pacakges. You can use the minimal one (from Werner) and if you need other modifications, you can always use the second.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Altermundus' solution is closer to what `tufte-handout` does itself: You get exactly the same definition of `\@caption` if you load `hyperref` implicitly in the document class (i.e. without the `nohyper` option). So as things work (or break) exactly the same way as they do in the unmodified version, there is no additional source of error here.

Answer (score 8):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) *does* indeed modify `\@caption`. If font is the only concern, then the following patch is sufficient:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd
  {\@caption}% <cmd>
  {\normalsize}% <search>
  {\@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification}% <replace>
  {\typeout{caption patched}}% <success>
  {}% <failure
\makeatother
```

[image]

It stems from `hyperref` issuing `\normalsize` within `\@caption` (a subsidiary macro called from within `\caption`) which resets the font. The above patch replaces that with the regular Tufte-class components.

Why is this required even though you do "exactly the same as loading `hyperref` at class-level? Because the class loads `hyperref` first, and then redefines its own `\caption` and `\@caption` macros, overwriting that of `hyperref`. In that sense, @Altermundus' answer is sufficient as well.

Comment: Thanks! You say "if font is the only concern"; are there other (insidious, not readily apparent) things I should be concerned about if I load `hyperref` before Tufte?

Comment: @Altermundus: It [looks like there might be](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56955/7844).