# What does "you have forgotten to use \caption" mean?

Tags: hyperref, errors, captions, tufte

I'm stumped by an error I'm getting, when I try to render a *Tufte-LaTeX* document using `hypcap` and `hyperref`. For example, even a minimal document consisting of

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-handout}

\makeatletter
\let\tufte@caption\@caption    % Protect caption from hyperref 
\RequirePackage{hyperref}   
\let\@caption\tufte@caption    % See -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46838 
\makeatother
\RequirePackage[all]{hypcap}   % See -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27349

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\caption{An empty figure.}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

causes an error:

```
Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \caption.
```

What is causing this error, and how can I avoid it?

---

If it comes to it, I'd settle for giving up some features provided by either `hypcap` of `hyperref` (e.g., linking to figures) if that's what it takes to keep things stable. I *don't* want to give up the visible effects of the Tufte style.

Comment: I suspect that `hypcap` is upset about `\caption` not being defined as expected.

Comment: @egreg: Does `hypcap` not work with Tufte at all then? Or has `hyperref` done something?

Comment: `hypcap` uses the interface of `hyperref` located in the definition of `\@caption` patched by `hyperref`, so `hypcap` is dependent on this redefinition. But your code prevents the redefinition of `\@caption` by the `hyperref` package and therefore the `hypcap` package is doomed to fail. Remedy: Do not suppress the redefinition of `\@caption` but offer a new definition of `\@caption` which works with both, `tufte` and `hyperref`. (Unfortunately I'm too short on time at the moment to code this for you, but I'm confident that someone here will...)

Comment: I just took a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46838: Try out the solution from Werner (instead the one from Altermundus which drops the modifications of `\@caption` done by the `hyperref` package)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: It's not clear to me how to apply that answer in this situation (e.g. where to "put it").

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I just tried it out, Werners solution does not help here, too. So one need to write its very own version of `\@caption` here. I could do that, but will not able to code it until week-end.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Thanks! I'm stumped. I've added to the end of my question with a clarification of what tradeoffs could be made, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check the following on something larger? I'm certain we lose `nameref` support with this (because I wanted to avoid the parameters-of-@caption thing), but there might be more side effects, and I'm not familiar enough with tufte to spot if something's wrong from a single caption on an empty page:

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-handout}

\makeatletter
\let\mytufte@@caption\@caption    % Protect caption from hyperref 
\RequirePackage{hyperref}   

\RequirePackage[all]{hypcap}   % See -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27349

\let\mytufte@caption\@tufte@caption
\def\@tufte@caption{%
  \global\@capstartfalse\mytufte@caption
}
% this should be highly conditional on presence
% of the right versions of hyperref et al.
\def\@caption{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname iftrue\endcsname
    \global\let\@currentHref\hc@currentHref
  \else
    \hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}%
  \fi
  \mytufte@@caption
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{An empty figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```